# Faster JasperReports templates compilation in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new in JasperReports.

In my application I have use iReport to generate JasperReports templates and use that templates to generate PDF.
My application is large scale java based enterprise application so, in my application need to generate more that 100k PDFs.

I want to compile templates file only once at starting of pdf generation. Is there any way I can do it?

And one more question I would like to that performance is major in my application so, I want performance also. So, is there any best way in java through which jrxml compilation and pdf generation is going faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can compile `jrxml` files with iReport or you can compile templates with Apache Ant task or you can compile files with JasperReports API.

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks for comment. But i am using java technology and and in that i want to generate pdf with based on xml and template is jrxml

Comment: I think that what Alex means is that you should have all your jrxml files precompiled, during the build of your application. There is no reason to compile the jrxml files at runtime.

Comment: @JBNizet . You mean to say that when i build application it automatically build my jrxml also. You might be right but my jrxml is dynamic . I am getting my jrxml from database so, in application i have to use  JasperCompileManager.compileReport(strJrxmlFileName).

Comment: And why don't you store the compiled report in database? If tyhat's not an option, just use a cache which remembers the compiled version of every jrxml file. Guava's CacheBuilder should be handy to implement it: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: @JBNizet.. You are right. I got my ans . Thanks You so much . Now i can do it. Thanks Again............

Answer (score 3):

A simple way, you may need to use file class.
Compare File timestamp, if jrxml neweer then the compiled report compile it again.
So you will have cache implicited.

Be aware of java gc... in dev environment regarding multiple redeployments I had to restart Tomcat, production environment not noticed.

But dynamic templates... hooo... You are brave!! Why Dynamic? Reports should just sweet for a couple of situations, just the values changes, so template compilation is the same for diferent values...

I know My answer is months away, but for the other, may usefull!